# batidor de globo, globo batidor o batidor de huevo? usos y origen

Tags: vocabulario-técnico

Siendo del Norte de México me acabo de encontrar con el utensilio de cocina:

> "globo batidor"

Esta es la primera vez que escucho que se refieren a él de esa manera, como "batidor de globo", "globo batidor" o simplemente "globo". Al parecer esta forma es muy común y usada, pero la única manera en la que yo lo conozco es "batidor de huevo".

Han escuchado que se refieran a él de esa manera o alguien conoce el nombre original y por qué ha cambiado?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se llama así porque su forma resembla un globo:

[image] [image]

en contraste con los [otros tipos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batidor#Tipos) de batidor:

[image]

En algunos dialectos por [metonimia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonimia) el nombre *globo* se ha transformado en el término general para un batidor:

- batidor > batidor globo > globo

En inglés también se llama este tipo de batidor especificamente "Balloon whisk".